# I can't disable the "click to minimize" feature

Tags: gnome, gsettings, minimize, dash-to-dock

I recently installed Ubuntu 22.04 and, following an online guide, I activated the "click to minimize" feature. I don't exactly remember, but I believe I used the CLI way, executing the following command:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.shell.extensions.dash-to-dock click-action 'minimize-or-overview'
```

I've been happy with it for a few weeks, then I wanted to go back to the default behavior. I've tried all the methods I've found online, but none worked. In particular, I believe this is the most concise way to achieve my objective : `gsettings reset org.gnome.shell.extensions.dash-to-dock click-action`, but still Ubuntu minimized on click. I restarted the computer, it didn't work. If I check the status of the gsetting by running `gsettings get org.gnome.shell.extensions.dash-to-dock click-action` I get: 'focus-or-previews'

But it seems like the specified `gsetting` doesn't affect Ubuntu's behavior at all. I also tried GUI methods, but it didn't work anyway.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, but I found [this site](https://itsfoss.com/click-to-minimize-ubuntu/) that helped me. Here is the code you should use:

`gsettings reset org.gnome.shell.extensions.dash-to-dock click-action`

although you used

`gsettings set org.gnome.shell.extensions.dash-to-dock click-action 'minimize-or-overview'`

instead of

`gsettings set org.gnome.shell.extensions.dash-to-dock click-action 'minimize'`

which is what I used, so it may not work.